# Let click go through the mt-tooltip component

Tags: css, angular, angular-material

I'm using the mat-tooltip component.

We can see here, when hovering the red with the mouse, over the red container, angular does add the `mat-tooltip-component` on top of it.

but as long as I'm hovering the `mat-tooltip-component`, I'm unable to click on the `admin` button that we see here.

I tried to disable the pointer event to the `mat-tooltip-component` like follow

```css
mat-tooltip-component {
  pointer-events: none;
}
```

But now the tooltip wont disappear anymore.
surely because it listen to the "on mouse leave" of this element...

Does anybody face the same problem and had found a solution to it ?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can disable the `mat-tooltip-component` interaction by declaring it in the `app.module.ts` with the `disableTooltipInteractivity` set to `true`.

```js
import { MAT_TOOLTIP_DEFAULT_OPTIONS } from '@angular/material/tooltip'

@NgModule({
// ...
 providers: [
    {
      provide: MAT_TOOLTIP_DEFAULT_OPTIONS,
      useValue: {
        showDelay: 0,
        hideDelay: 0,
        touchendHideDelay: 1500,
        position: 'above',
        disableTooltipInteractivity: true, // <-- Should do the trick
      },
    },
 ]
})
```

Comment: Nice one - not sure whey they'd default it to 'abusive' anyway.  Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I had the same struggle. I had an Idea with ur code snippet.
Just write it like this

```
mat-tooltip-component {
  &:hover {
    pointer-events: none;
  }
}
```

and it works perfectly for me.

Thanks for the idea.

Comment: Hi Jonas & thx for your answer. I did find the answer to my question and had forgotten to add it here. 

I've added it now, please do use this instead of your solution since it's cleaner. 

Cheers